# How to get the value of an input file-field in the input field in edit form ? symfony

Tags: forms, file, symfony, twig

i'm woriking on a symfony project, I have there an form to create an object, in the form there is an input field type file. When I upload files there it is no problem, and I can read the file and show it in the twig template. But when I want to edit the entry values of all fields (type string) get mapped to there input fields, just input field type of file, they don't get mapped.!

How to deal files in edit form? I mean how to get the files in there input fields?

Best regards

Comment: You will have to track the filenames, you could create another entity called files and relate it to the user entity as a one to many..

Comment: The file input is only used for uploading the file. After uploading you should handle storing/relating to the file on your own. As Bossman suggested, you could create an entity to track the filename that relates to the file you just uploaded. In your edit view, you show the related (file) entity that tracked the name